# Comparing Vectors and printing bool

Tags: c++, vector, for-loop

I am trying to make my code compare two vectors. Both vectors will be compared with the same amount of `int`s. I want it to output `Yes` if all the `int`s in `redCups` are less than `GreenCups`. And output `No` if any cup at all in the `redCups` is larger than `greenCups`.

Am I tackling this right?

```
    bool beb = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < numCups; i++)
    {
        if (redCups[i]<greenCups[i])
        {
           beb = false;
        }
    }

    if (beb == true)
    {
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    }
    if else ( beb == false)
       cout << "No" << endl;
```

Comment: Does your code work correctly when you try it with some test data sets? The structure of your logic looks okay, but you may have some tests backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `std::equal` algorithm to compare each pair of elements from two containers. By default it returns `true` if all pairs are equal but it's easy to test each pair for `less` or `less_equal` instead.

```
bool beb = std::equal(redCups.begin(), redCups.end(), greenCups.begin(), std::less<int>());
```

Answer (score 0):

the code is good but there is a little mistake, you want to get yes if all `redCups` < `greenCups`, so no if any `redCups` **>=** `greenCups`. Code :

```
if (redCups[i] >= greenCups[i]) // you have to decide whether if its > or >=
        {
           beb = false;
        }
```

I suppose that you have checked before that `redCups` and `greenCups` contain at least `numCups` of ints :

```
if (redCups.size() >= numCups && greenCups.size() >= numCups)
{
    //your code : (bool beb = true; .................... cout << "No" << endl;)
}
```

Comment: if you want to check this you could return an int : 1 for true, 0 for false and -1 if one of the vectors contains less than `numCups` ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;

    v1.push_back(5);
    v1.push_back(9);
    v1.push_back(4);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(2);

    v2.push_back(10);
    v2.push_back(12);
    v2.push_back(9);
    v2.push_back(4);
    v2.push_back(3);

    bool beb = true;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
        if(!(v1[i]<v2[i]))
        {
            beb = false;
            break;
        }

    if (beb == true)
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No" << endl;

    cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

I modified your code slightly and got this. It seems to work for me.